# Encountering issues with the domain statement in proc surveyfreq, unadjusted proc surveylogistic, and adjusted proc surveylogistic procedures

Tags: sas

I am having issues including the domain statement in my proc surveyfreq, unadjusted proc surveylogistic, and adjusted proc surveylogistic procedures.

I have used code that I've found on SAS community websites, but I keep getting error messages. I am trying to set the domain of these procedures for agecategory 1 and 2. Agecategory 1= '18-49 years' and Agecategory 2= '50 years and older'. I am only excluding one age category from the analysis, Agecategory=0 which is people 0-17 years of age. I have turned to the domain statement after learning that I cannot use the by or where statements when using the surveyfreq and surveylogistic procedures.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Please find my code below:

**Surveyfreq Procedure:**

```
*run proc surveyfreq for demographic variables;
proc surveyfreq data=GSS1;
weight wtssnr;
tables agecategory*(sex marital sexornt racecen1 racecen2 racecen3 degree wrkstat income16 region); 
STRATUM vstrat;
CLUSTER vpsu;
FORMAT degree degree. wrkstat wrkstat. income16 totalfamilyincome. regionregion. agecategory agecategory. marital marital. sex sex. racecen1 racecen1mention. racecen2 racecen2mention. racecen3 racecen3mention. sexornt sexornt.; 
run;
```

**Unadjusted Surveylogistic Procedure**

```
*Step 9: Unadjusted logistic regression using proc surveylogistic;
proc surveylogistic data=GSS1;
class agecategory/param=ref;
model condom (event= 'Used last time') = agecategory/df=infinity;
strata vstrat;
cluster vpsu;
weight wtssnr;
format condom condom. agecategory agecategory.;
run;
```

**Adjusted Surveylogistic Procedure**

```
*Step 13: Run an adjusted logistic regression model using proc surveylogistic;
proc surveylogistic data=GSS1;
class condom agecategory marital evidu evcrack partners sexfreq hivtest sexornt racecen1 degree region income16 wrkstat/param=ref;
model condom (event='Used last time')=agecategory marital evidu evcrack partners sexfreq hivtest sexornt racecen1 degree region income16 wrkstat/link=glogit df=infinity;
STRATUM vstrat;
CLUSTER vpsu;
weight wtssnr;
FORMAT condom condom. sex sex. agecategory agecategory. marital marital. evidu evidu. idu30 idu30days. evcrack evcrack. crack30 crack30lastuse. partners partners. sexfreq sexfreq. hivtest hivtest. sexornt sexornt. racecen1 racecen1mention. degree degree. region region. income16 totalfamilyincome. wrkstat wrkstat.;
run;
```